# Position image on background(background size changes)

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I try to position images on my site background with css. I want those images stay always same position on my background. But my background image change size and images move...

background:

```
html{
background: url("../images/example.gif") no-repeat bottom right fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

image:

```
.image{
position: fixed;
right: 219.5px;
top: 368px;
}
```

any ideas how i can keep image always same position?

Comment: Please share any working demo/jsfiddle or live link where we can check this issue so we can help in better way...thanx

Answer (score 0):

Please try this out. The css may solve your problem :)

```
    body {
           background: url('../images/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
           -webkit-background-size: cover;
           -moz-background-size: cover;
           -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            color:#fff;
            background-color:#FFF;
            position: relative;
}
```

If the above once does not work try the codes below

```
    body
       {
        background-image: url("../images/background.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
       }
```

Comment: test your answer, before posting

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

```
html{
background: url("../images/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        color:#fff;
        background-color:#FFF;
        position: relative;
}
```

css:

```
.image{
position: fixed;
right: 219.5px;
top: 368px;
}
```

[DEMO PAGE](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: please see the demo page @AsdMan